# How to execute large MySQL data-insert script file using command line in Windows 7?

Tags: mysql, windows-7, unicode, command-line, run-script

I'm new to MySQL. I am interested how to do this via command line; I've tried but I get NO logging in the console output and the character set is not `utf-8`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since your SQL script doesn't contain any character set configuration directives, `mysql` just runs in its default character set Latin1. To change the default character set, start `mysql` like this:

```
mysql -e "source /path-to-backup/backup-file.sql" db_name --default-character-set=UTF8
```

Answer (score 12):

```
mysql -e "source /path-to-backup/backup-file.sql" db_name
```

or

```
mysql db_name < backup-file.sql
```

You probably need `-u username -p`, too in your command.

[mysqldump doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: I've tried `mysql db_name < backup-file.sql` but utf-8 data are lost

Comment: Did you try both, is the correct data in the SQL file to begin with?

Comment: Unicode? UTF-8? What's it going to be? Anyway, how does the sql file start? Files created with `mysqldump` contain all the relevant parameters to set the necessary encoding options, I believe; is your file a straight dump file?

Comment: @Kerrek This is my sample script in utf8 http://db.tt/IyNbFAj. Have tried successful using `Navicat execute sql file`but running from commandline failed

Comment: Ah, your script is missing any character set configuration commands... (take a look at the result of `mysqldump` to see what I mean). You could try passing `--default-character-set=UTF8` to `mysql` maybe.

Comment: @Kerrek Adding the `--default-character-set=UTF8` to the command line solve it. Please add it as a separate answer so as I'll pick it up as accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\<installation_path>>\bin>mysql -u<<user>> -p  database_name < your_sql_file.sql
```

could be used if you are getting access issues `like ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

hope that helps !!